# Where to calculate the duration?

Tags: thingsboard

Im still new to TB, but I've been searching to a solution to see the duration.

The scenario could be a engine on/off state, how do make a rule chain that calculates the duration when its on?

Ive tried all sorts of solution but can't really figure out the right way to make it.

Tried to make a rule with the Delta enrichment, bu no luck there.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the telemetry coming in - if its reporting on/off, or the last time the engine started.

If incoming telemetry reports 'engine_on' as a start time, you could use the 'Calculate delta' enrichment node to display the running time.

If the telemetry reports 'on' of 'off', you could create a custom attribute for your entity to store ‘start time’ and ‘duration’. In your rule chain, add a 'save attributes' (or maybe 'save timeseries') node which updates the 'start time' attribute. Duration can be calculated with a script node accessing the attribute content. (To access fetched attributes in other nodes you can use this template ‘metadata.temperature’)